# Replacing width and height in url

Tags: java, string, substring, indexof

What's the simplest way of changing the w= number and h= number?

Example of url:

https://test.com/photos/226109/test-photo-226109.jpeg?w=**1260**&h=**750**&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop

I have to dynamically change bolded parts.

I can extract the value of w like this:

```
  s = s.substring(s.indexOf("=") + 1, s.indexOf("&"));
```

But how could I change it?
I tried searching Stackoverflow, but couldn't find anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood correctly you are trying to replace the values after the `=` sign for `h` and `w`.

You can simply do that with RegEx as follows:

```
"https://test.com/photos/226109/test-photo-226109.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop"
                        .replaceAll("w=\\d+", "w=NEW_VALUE").replaceAll("&h=\\d+", "&h=NEW_VALUE")
```

What is happening above is that we first find the patern that matches `w=AnyNumberHere` and we replace the entire section with `w=NEW_VALUE`. Likewise we replace `&h=AnyNumberHere` with `&h=NEW_VALUE`

This solution is not length depended, therefore if the URL has a variable length this will still work, and will even work if the value `h=123` or `w=1234` for example do not exist ;)

Comment: Thanks. Just what I was looking for!

Comment: @core_m Glad i helped! :D. As a followup, i didn't know what the length of the number would be after the = sign, so i couldnt controll that. if you know the length like if it is between 1 and 10 characters long) we can limit it!

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can use String replaceAll method. Example of use:

```
String string =
    "https://test.com/photos/226109/test-photo-226109." +
        "jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop";
String replacedString = string
    .replaceAll(string.substring(string.indexOf("=") + 1, 
        string.indexOf("&")), "1000");
```

Answer (score -1):

When you get your numbers from string you can convert it to StringBuffer.
Like this

```
String s = new String("https://test.com/photos/226109/test-photo-226109.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop");
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s);
sb.replace(s.indexOf("w=") + 2, s.indexOf("&"), "2000");
sb.replace(s.indexOf("h=") + 2, s.indexOf("&"), "2000");
s = sb.toString();
```

Comment: If the URL is of variable length then this will fail, it will replace the wrong section of the URL thus corrupting it.

Comment: i meant 12 and 15 are values of s.indexOf("=") + 1

Comment: Still your code is prone to errors. For instance if the url doesn't contain `=` it will error, also replacing from the first `=` sign until the next `=` sign would corrupt the url :S In the example above it would make it look something like: `https://test.com/photos/226109/test-photo-226109.jpeg?w=2000750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop` which removes the `&h=` part and merges the value after it with 2000 which is the replacement value :S

Comment: Thats better, but still would error if `w=` or `h=` where not in the url for some reason ;) yourse works as well though in the example provided by the OP